# How to deactivate the text, that appears, when you hovering over topbar tabs?

Tags: themes, headers, text

I want to deactivate the text, that appears, when you're hovering over topbar tabs (I've marked it red in the screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

Im using the Oshine theme.

Greetz

Comment: what version of the theme?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely configured as a `title` attribute somewhere in the template files, or in a `functions.php`-like file. I would first find where they are configured, and try to change them from there.

Otherwise, you can still use jQuery to remove the title attributes with something like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $("header nav a").attr("title", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't just add JS to remove it when you can go to the source.  Search your theme's function.php file for a line similar to the following and comment it out.

```
 add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'be_themes_menu_link_atts', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove them by adding this code to your `functions.php` and they will be gone.

```
function remove_title_attributes($input) {
    return preg_replace('/\s*title\s*=\s*(["\']).*?\1/', '', $input);
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'remove_title_attributes' );
```